# Perl LWP::Simple won't GET some URLs

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a basic webscraping program in Perl. For some reason it is not working correctly and I don't have the slightest clue as to why.

Just the first part of my code where I am getting the content (just saving all of the HTML code from the webpage to a variable) does not work with certain websites.

I am testing it by just printing it out, and it does not print anything out with this specific website. It works with some other sites, but not all.

Is there another way of doing this that will work?

```
#use strict;
use LWP::Simple qw/get/;
use LWP::Simple qw/getstore/;


## Grab a Web page, and throw the content in a Perl variable.
my $content = get("https://jobscout.lhh.com/Portal/Page/ResumeProfile.aspx?Mode=View&ResumeId=53650");
print $content;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*? What happens?

Comment: Side-note: Combine your two `use` statements into `use LWP::Simple qw/get getstore/;`

Comment: @pts Like when i run it in the terminal; it doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: Please *never* comment out `use strict`: it is a lifeline when you are debugging and you just threw it away. You should also *always* `use warnings` for additional help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a badly-written web site there. The request times out with a `500 Internal Server Error`.

I can't suggest how to get around it, but the site almost certainly uses JavaScript as well which `LWP` doesn't support, so I doubt if an answer would be much use to you.

---

**Update**

It looks like the site has been written so that it goes crazy if there is no `Accept-Language` header in the request.

The full [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) module is necessary to set it up, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 10);
my $url = 'https://jobscout.lhh.com/Portal/Page/ResumeProfile.aspx?Mode=View&ResumeId=53650';

my $resp = $ua->get($url, accept_language => 'en-gb,en', );
print $resp->status_line, "\n\n";
print $resp->decoded_content;
```

This returns with a status of `200 OK` and some HTML.

Comment: So if LWP doesn't support javascript; what can I use that will support it?

Comment: @Michael_Branco [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox)

Comment: @Michael_Branco: The [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) module
 is probably the one I've most often seen suggested. There's also [`WWW::Scripter`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Scripter) which is based on the Perl JavaScript engine [`JE`](https://metacpan.org/module/JE). I am certain there are others.

Comment: Thank you that works!! Now is it asking too much that Regular expressions will work correctly using this? Or will it be messed up because of the poorly written code?

Comment: The site is only preventing you from getting the page at all under some strange circumstances. The problem has nothing to do with using regular expressions on the content once you get it. But you should use a module like [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder) to parse HTML - it's asking for trouble to try using regex patterns.

Comment: @Borodin Yeah for some reason, my regex is correct, but from the code you have provided, it doesn't save any code that was generated from the Javascript

Comment: @Michael_Branco: Yeah, like I said, `LWP` will fetch only the page's contents. If the page uses JavaScript to modify itself then you need something more. `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` uses an installed Firefox browser to process the page, while `WWW::Scripter` has its own inbuilt ECMAScript engine. I hope you don't expect this stuff to be easy? Many sites are coded specifically to resist access like this, for instance so that they benefit from embedded advertising links. You have a long journey ahead.

Comment: @Borodin Yeah I have realized this already when I had trouble just trying to install WWW::Mehcanize::Firefox lol but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To interact with a website that uses Javascript, I would advise that you use the following module:[`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $url = "https://jobscout.lhh.com/Portal/Page/ResumeProfile.aspx?Mode=View&ResumeId=53650"

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get($url);

print $mech->status();

my $content = $mech->content();
```